# STM32 Execution Time

Tags: stm32, stm32f4, debugging

I'm working with an STM32F4 discovery board and I want to calculate how much time it takes to do some tasks. I'm using Atollic with an SW4STM32 debugger. I cannot figure out how to do it.

I've read something about sending messages to the console and then measuring that time, but don't know how to send messages to the console. Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: I usually use an oscilloscope, but the DWT unit in the Cortex core is great for this: http://embeddedb.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-count-cycles-on-arm-cortex-m.html ... I often use it to log max and min execution times of my main loop when doing my firmware timing analysis. It is also handy to create those hideous fixed delays that are so often overused.

Comment: You're asking two different things. What part do you actually need help with? Measuring the time or printing to the console?

Comment: try the systick or dwt timer, avoid hal libraries when doing the measurement they add unknowns to the measurement.  Use nops in the bootstrap to adjust the fetch alignment and to approach a min/max on the time.  Try ram vs rom if you need more performance, the rom is often the first bottleneck to performance, with an STM32 though they have caching you cannot turn off (with some marketing term) that makes the rom appear to be faster than it is.  would recommend testing in ram, then degrade that number by some factor then run in rom.

Comment: peformance is not necessarily linear on these devices, particularly if using a HAL, try your candidate frequency settings, if you change then re-test.

Comment: like the timer, if you use a scope on a gpio, using the HAL to setup the gpio is fine (although much easier not to), but the store to change the gpio state you dont want to use a hal for to reduce how much it affects the performance.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to other answers, you can use an oscilloscope if you have one.

At the beginning of your task, set an unused pin (or an LED, etc) high.  Then set it low directly after the task completes.  The o-scope can show you the duration.

Comment: Keep in mind that if your accessing the pin functions through the HAL or through a function your going to be a few clocks off for all of the instructions that need to happen jumping in and out of the function. (if that makes any sense)

Comment: Very true, @laptop2d!  I don't know if he's counting nanoseconds or milliseconds :)  Or full seconds, I suppose...

Comment: Thats a good idea! I only want to know how much time does it take to do some process. I think the simplest idea is to set a timer in 0 , run the process and then read the value of my timer. Thanks for your advise!

Answer (score 3):

1) Use the profiler included with your compiler (if it has one)
2) Use one of the timers, start the timer right before and after the code you wish to time.
3) Look at the assembly code and start [counting clock cycles](http://www.st.com/resource/en/programming_manual/cd00228163.pdf) by finding them in the programming manual and finding how many clock cycles will be used, get the total number of clock cycles and multiply it by the core frequency.

Comment: Be careful with clock cycle counting on cortex chips. You have to check wait states on your buses and, in some situations, stalls on the instruction pipeline. It can be done though.

Comment: Counting does not not work, as the instructions are in the queue and are in the different decode / execution stage.

Comment: @PeterJ If the code path has branches or instructions that take multiple clock cycles you'll have to account for that.

Comment: @laptop2d there are more to be taken into consideration - any event triggered (like interrupt) will flush the cache etc. etc. Clock cycles counting does not work on ARM devices!!

Comment: So turn interupts off in the section that your counting and leave them off

Comment: it is trivial to demonstrate that counting instructions does not work.  fetch alignment, caching, load/store vs non-load/store, ram vs rom, etc.  Taking the same machine code segment you can see that it executes at different speeds on the same cpu, without interrupts or other similar interference, those just make it less consistent.

Comment: internal timers, dont need the dwt, the systick is fine, or others, and using a scope if you have one and a gpio can help, but at the same time you affect the performance by measuring the performance.

Comment: Yes a scope is an external time reference, have to degrade the performance by the accuracy of the crystal, or try many parts and find the worst, etc.  Once you get a measurement in units of clocks, you still have to adjust based on the accuracy of the clock reference to wall clock time.

Answer (score 2):

I usually toggle a pin and measure time using oscilloscope. This is the method least prone to errors. If you want to do it in code then I would suggest using systick timer set to microsecond precision (SystemCoreClock / 1000000). However this always has drift depending on the main crystal precision so you may want to use rtc to count exactly how many cycles you get in 1s and then scale your results accordingly.

Comment: the systick timer drift or not runs off the same clock as the core cpu, so is the most accurate (the DWT is just another timer on the same clock so can work as well).  Granted if there are other clock domains on other clock references then you have to deal with that.

Comment: The system tick timer is only as accurate as your LSE crystal which can deviate from spec by several %. You can easily have scenarios where you get 1100000us in one second. So you absolutely have to compensate for this inaccuracy by scaling microsecond counter to number of microseconds measured in one second according to the real time clock peripheral which runs off of the 32768khz crystal that is specifically designed to be accurate, but does not give you microsecond precision.

Comment: the cpu cannot execute more instructions because the clock is slow.  drift in the clock is not relevant to clock cycles required to peform a specific task (all other factors held constant).  So wall clock time only measures one chips nuances not how long it takes to do something.  Later once you optimize the number of instructions you can compensate for jitter in the clock or the accuracy of the crystal.  depending on the clock you can have variations during the course of a day or an hour that wont see cycles per task.

Comment: internal and external at the same time is fine just dont neglect internal.  bad measurements are unfortunately very common any measurement method and lead to bad assumptions and experiments.

Comment: an rtc is only as accurate as the clock it uses, you cant generically say an RTC is more accurate then an mcus timer as they are both just dumb timers driven off of a clock.  note that some (STM32 and others) mcus have RTCs so you may be confusing the OP if they use a HAL and the internal RTC they might not be better off depending on the clocks.  if they have the more accurate crystal hooked up they can sometimes simply use that without the extra work to use the rtc.  basically an rtc is not automatically more accurate than a scope or other measurement.